# is epsilon always less than 1?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

I was working on a proof of a limit and i wondered if epsilon should always be $$0< \varepsilon< 1$$. while working with limits is epsilon defined as such?

Comment: It doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no, **but** if $\epsilon>1$ then any value $|z|<\frac12$ would also satisfy $|z|<\epsilon.$

So, effectively, for limits, you can assume $\epsilon <1$ or $0<\epsilon<\alpha$ for any real $\alpha.$

This is true because of how $\epsilon$ is used in limits. If you prove it for a particular $\epsilon_0>0,$ then it is true for all $\epsilon\geq \epsilon_0.$

---

So if $P(\epsilon)$ is shorthand for the statement:

> There exists an $N$ such that if $n>N,$ then $|a_n-L|<\epsilon.$ (Condition for $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L.$)

Then if $P(\epsilon_1)$ is true, and $\epsilon_2>\epsilon_1,$ then $P(\epsilon_2)$ is also true, using the same value $N.$

You get the same logic for continuous limited like $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L.$